# How to draw in \tikzmath mode?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Somehow, this code isn't working

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand*{\xMax}{6}
\newcommand*{\yMax}{6}
\tikzmath{
  \k = 0;
  for \i in {0,0.5,...,\xMax} {
    if \i == \xMax then {
      \draw [very thin,gray] (\i,0) -- (\i,\yMax);
    } else {
      \draw [very thin,gray] (\i,0) -- (\i,\yMax) node[below=0.0cm] at ([xshift=0.275cm]\i,0) {$X_{\k}$};
    }
    \k = \k + 1;
  }
  for \i in {0,0.5,...,\yMax} {
      if \i == \yMax then {
        \draw [very thin,gray] (0,\i) -- (\xMax,\i);
      } else {
        \draw [very thin,gray] (0,\i) -- (\xMax,\i) node [left] at ([yshift=0.25cm]0,\i) {$\i$};
      }
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And I am failing at finding out why. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If you can, do the draw commands outside `tikzmath`. I have used variables outside before, you just have to define them inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\draw` and company within `tikzmath`. The rules for that are explained in section **59.7 Executing Code Outside the Parser** of pgfmanual v3.1.5:
[image]

Then you need to be way more careful with spaces and `;`. For instance, in

```
for \i in {0,0.5,...,\yMax} {
```

you cannot have a space between `}` and `{`. Also, each `if` and loop needs to get terminated by a `;`. If you follow these rules, you get

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand*{\xMax}{6}
\newcommand*{\yMax}{6}
\tikzmath{real \i;
  int \k;
  \k = 0;
  for \i in {0,0.5,...,\xMax}{
    if \i == \xMax then {
      {\draw [very thin,gray] (\i,0) -- (\i,\yMax);};
    } else {
      {\draw [very thin,gray] (\i,0) -- (\i,\yMax) node[below=0.0cm] at
      ([xshift=0.275cm]\i,0) {$X_{\k}$};};
    };
    \k = \k + 1;
  };
  for \i in {0,0.5,...,\yMax}{
      if \i == \yMax then {
        {\draw [very thin,gray] (0,\i) -- (\xMax,\i);};
      } else {
        {\draw [very thin,gray] (0,\i) -- (\xMax,\i) node [left] at
        ([yshift=0.25cm]0,\i) {$\i$};};
      };
  };
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]